# What is the best approach for passing parameters from one scene to another scene in react-native

Tags: listview, react-native, detailsview

A simple question for which you write well ReactNative.

What is the best approach for passing parameters from one scene to another scene with ListView where there are details of an item.

```
  _renderRow (rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow) {
    return (
        <View>
                <TouchableHighlight 
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigator.push({name: 'Item1', data: rowData.name, rowID: rowID})}>
                  <Text>{rowID}.- {rowData.name}</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    )
  };
```

Just I know that you can pass simple data in the route object in the navigator.push, as shown in the code.

How to pass more complex objects between scenes?
What would be the correct way Native React? any example?

Comment: Consider using Flux pattern : https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html ,  and on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs-flux

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the answer.
Using 'passProps' can send data, but I have to remember that in the definition of rederScene have to describe the same parameters

The Navigator defining props in route Item1

```
<Navigator ref='navigator'
  initialRoute={{name: 'Home'}}
  renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
    switch (route.name) {
    case 'Home': return (
      <Home navigator={navigator}/>
      );
    case 'Item1': return (
      <Item1 navigator={navigator} rowID={route.rowID||-1} passProps={route.passProps||{}}/>
      );    
    }}/>
```

The ListView component passing props to navigator in the renderRow

```
  _renderRow (rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow) {
    return (
        <View>
                <TouchableHighlight 
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigator.push({name: 'Item1', rowID: rowID, passProps: rowData})}>
                  <Text>{rowID}.- {rowData.name}</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    )
  };
```

And finally, the Item1 component with the props, and saving in state.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.setState( { 
        data: this.props.passProps
    });
  };

  render () {
    console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <View>
            <Text>{this.props.rowID}</Text>
            <Text>{this.state.data.name}</Text>
            <SimpleButton
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigator.pop()}
                  customText='Back' />
            </View> 
        );
  }
```

If you have any sugestions... this is a good place.

Thanks